# Why is my Hybrid App WKWebView unexpectedly reloading

Tags: wkwebview, ios13, ios-camera

Since upgrading to IOS 13, the WKWebView in my hybrid app unexpectedly reloads after invoking the camera app.

The app is also requesting location at the same time, so I wondered if this was somehow due to the app requesting location whilst being backgrounded to bring the camera app to the front. However the app is not terminated, it is simply the WKWebView that reloads.

So perhaps it is a memory issue, the camera app probably uses a lot of memory. However I cannot see what would cause the WKWebView to be reloaded.

It is causing me a lot of grief because the main functionality of the app is all inside the javascript so the context behind taking the photo is lost when the WKWebView reloads.

Anyone any ideas what could be causing this. It all worked fine from IOS7 up to IOS12 (obviously UIWebView in the app's early days)

I have run this in XCode and watched to see if there are any error messages in the console, but all I get displayed is

```
[BackgroundTask] Background Task 2 ("Called by MyApp, from -[BackgroundTaskManager beginNewBackgroundTask]"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x100e6c180, CAMHDRButton) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x100e43ee0, CAMTimerButton) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just realised that this is because I moved the WKWebView generation code from ViewDidLoad to ViewDidAppear and I failed to check that it was not appearing for the first time.